# AngularJS select not showing selected value

Tags: html, angularjs

***Controller***

```
$scope.industries= [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name1", 
 }, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Name2"
 }
];
```

> When assign `$scope.filling_type = 2` in controller,I want to select "Name2"
>   option in the select.

***View***

```
<select ng-model="filling_type">
  <option ng-repeat="industry in industries"
  ng-value="industry.name">{{industry.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In this case no option selected.

Comment: Isn't it for the capital "I" in `{{Industry.name}}` ?

Comment: made that mistake when i post this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend getting used to `ng-options` in the select element instead of `ng-repeat`ing in the option element because of increased flexibility and performance. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.industries= [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name1", 
 }, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Name2"
 }
];

$scope.filling_type = 2; // set default option here, using 2 from OP
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<select 
    ng-model="filling_type"
    ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in industries"> 
</select>
<p>Filling Type: {{filling_type}}</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are binding name as value, you should set the name property as the *`filling_type`*

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.industries= [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Name1", 
 }, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Name2"
 }
];

$scope.filling_type = "Name2";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<select ng-model="filling_type">
  <option ng-repeat="industry in industries"
  ng-value="industry.name">{{industry.name}}</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: `ng-value="industry.name"` is needed now?